# Bootstrap grid acrobations

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

does anybody know if there is any possibility to make something like this for lg displays:

```
1 | 2.1 |2.2 | 3.1
  |     |    |-----
  |     |    | 3.2
```

resizing to tablets:

```
1 | 3.2 | 3.1
-------------
2.1  |  2.2
```

and when resizing to mobiles:

```
1   | 3.2
----------
   3.1
----------
   2.1
----------
   2.2
```

I was trying to do it on many different ways but did not succeed. I will be very glad for help.

Comment: You can get those layouts but not the certain numbers in the correct column/row. I.e. 3.2 cant go in the middle on tablet. To achieve this you will need to create an entirely different container for each view and hide dependent on device width. The downside to this is you will have to still load 3 sets of markup. If you want to do it fluid it will look like this on tablet: 1 | 2.1 |2.2 then 3.1| 3.2 below.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 separate views/containers for desired order and use relevant viewpoint breaks - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

As I said, the downside is the loading of markup/css even when its hidden.